# How to turn off iPhone 5 without having to use the screen or buttons

Tags: iphone, repair

My buttons are broken and my phone is locked how do I turn it off and turn it back on again?

Answer (score 2):

Let the battery die, that will shut down the phone. Once dead and off, plugging the phone in to charge will turn it back on. This is assuming both the power and home buttons do not work.

Comment: Yeah I waited for that but the phone is still stuck at the same percentage which is 75%

Comment: Depending on what iPhone it is you have days of standby left. For instance an iPhone 6 has 10 days worth of standby and the 6+ has 16 days. These times are when out on standby at 100%. You've got at least a week at 75%

Comment: What about the 5?

Comment: Is there any other way I could do to waste the battery faster?

Comment: Standby time of the iPhone 5 is up to 225 hours. If you have access to the home screen just play a bunch of videos to kill the battery. If you don't have access to the phone then no.

Comment: Can I plug it into my laptop and do something to fix this?

Comment: Also, if you do have access to the phone, you can use a virtual home button and power button. I believe it's in settings and accessibility.

Comment: To shut it off? No, I don't believe so. You can do a restore from backup

Comment: Can I do shut it down through the home button and power button but by the thing that appears on the screen when the buttons don't work?

Comment: I believe so yes, but you need to have access to the phone. Your question was how to do it when your phone is blocked, I assume this means locked?

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging it into a new PC when it asks Allow/ Disallow, it definitely come to slide to unlock screen, then go to Settings>General>Auto-Lock>Never.

Answer (score 0):

Simply manually disconnect the battery by removing the two bottom screws and then lifting the screen.

Once screen is up, unscrew the 3 battery connector shield screws and then disconnect battery flex. Re attach when ready